# Como leer archivos binarios de objetos con una lista. C++

Tags: c++, archivo, deserialize

necesito un programa que deserialice archivos binarios de la clase Paciente, esta clase cuenta con 5 atributos distintos, los cuales ya logro deserializar bien, el problema es que tengo una lista de objetos enfermedad sin una cantidad de enfermedades definida, por ejemplo:

Paciente.

id: 201707578, nombre: Pablo Agüero, telefono: 71747-5728, correo: tada05@hotmail.com, secuencia de adn: ACCGTA.
Lista de enfermedades: - Enfermedad1(Nombre: Varicela, secuencia: ACG) - Enfermedad2(Nombre: Rabia, secuencia: CGTA).

Ahora, todo lo serializa serializa bien en el archivo binario, el problema que es que este archivo almacena una cantidad n de pacientes.

Este es el código para deserializarlos:

```
size_t largoId;
    size_t largoNom;
    size_t largoTel;
    size_t largoCor;
    size_t largoSec;


    archivoBin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&largoId), sizeof(largoId));
    this->id.assign(largoId, ' ');
    archivoBin.read(&this->id[0], largoId);

    archivoBin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&largoNom), sizeof(largoNom));
    this->id.assign(largoNom, ' ');
    archivoBin.read(&this->nombre[0], largoNom);

    archivoBin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&largoTel), sizeof(largoTel));
    this->id.assign(largoTel, ' ');
    archivoBin.read(&this->telefono[0], largoTel);

    archivoBin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&largoCor), sizeof(largoCor));
    this->id.assign(largoCor, ' ');
    archivoBin.read(&this->correo[0], largoCor);

    archivoBin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&largoSec), sizeof(largoSec));
    this->id.assign(largoSec, ' ');
    archivoBin.read(&this->secuencia[0], largoSec);
```

Lo que no logro entender es como leer la lista de enfermedades sin llegar a leer el siguiente paciente

Comment: Si la cantidad de enfermedades no es fija, tienes que poner algún centinela en el archivo que indique que ya se ha terminado con la lista de enfermedades y que el siguiente dato corresponde a otro paciente.

Comment: Otra opción (poco o nada recomendable) podría ser considerar un espacio suficientemente grande para enfemedades, digamos 20, y rellenar con datos vacíos en caso de que no se tengan tantas, pero es poco óptimo e incluso se podría dar el caso de que un paciente superase el máximo de enfermedades consideradas.

Comment: Digamos que el sentinela que pongo es un fin de linea, entonces cómo puedo hacer la condición para encontrarlo?